# Can our own Alexa apps use multi-room music?

Tags: alexa, audio

Amazon's own music players let you specify which smartspeaker, or speaker group, audio should play on. ("Echo, play WNYC everywhere" or "downstairs" or whatever). Is there a straightforward way for our own Alexa apps to support this feature?

(Did a quick search of both the APIs and here, and didn't see an answer... I'd like to add it to the custom music player I'm hacking together.)

Comment: I'm assuming your referring to making a custom skill?  Also, what hardware are you working with?  What speakers?  Did you run across [this](https://www.amazon.com/Wright-Ventures-LLC-Speaker-Groups/dp/B07HGQGT6P/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top) during your search?

Comment: Yes, I'm writing a custom skill. (Currently using the Jovo framework for portability, but eventually I may need to reimplement it as native Alexa -- especially, I expect, if I want this feature.) Standard Amazon hardware, base Alexa and Echo units. The thing you pointed to would be nice if it worked, but it only supports Sonos speakers (which have their own synchronization protocol), not the general Alexa multi-room music synch.

Comment: Current evidence is that this is a much-requested, but still unsupported, feature. Well, grump.

Comment: Unfortunately it would seem so